# Images are not uploading to the specific folder when I switch to localhost to server

Tags: php, mysql

I uploaded my php website to a server and updated the username, password, db_name but not the server. After submitting the form data saved in DB but images not uploading into the folders. Should I have to change the path of uploading folder or the hosting server?

$upload="uploads/.$filename"; I used when i was in localhost, and now the I uploaded this form in servername/db/index.php

This is the current code when submitting a new image.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $temp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $upload="uploads/.$filename"; 
        $move=move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$upload);

        $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO member(member_image,id_img) VALUES '$filename','$filename1')"); }
?>
```

Comment: Check if you have right permissions to write in this directory.

Comment: also the path too

Comment: Can you post your code here ?

Comment: where should i use this?

Comment: <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username","passw","dbname") 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
   $temp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $upload="uploads/.$filename";
   $move=move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$upload);
   $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO  member(member_image,id_img) VALUES '$filename','$filename1')"); } ?>    @VigneshChinnaiyan

Comment: and the location of upload is  "servername/db/upload" and the index file is in "db" folder

Comment: Make sure the path to your uploads is the full path on the server. As I understand it, you never changed the path when moving the installation - even though the full path has likely changed. I'd also make sure that folder permissions are accurate. For most PHP web environments, folders run a chmod of 755, whilst most files are 644.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at your file manager and check for things like your server username, public domain and reference your location where  you want to upload your files as per your server for instance something like this here:

```
$targer_dir = "/home/server_username/publi_html/myuploads/";    
e.g $target_dir = "/home/jacksiroc/public_html/mymedia/images/
```

then ensure that you have the right permission to allow you to upload the files there.